# mysql_fetch_array returning false when mysql_num_rows says that there is data, why?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-num-rows

my table has 10 records, and mysql_num_rows says that there are 10 rows in the mysql resource, in phpMyAdmin I can see 10 rows, 
but when mysql_fetch_array is called, the first two times this works correctly, then the last 8 times it returns FALSE.

Why?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM building_types";
$building_types = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );// works
echo mysql_num_rows($building_types); // prints 10
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($building_types); 
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $num_rows ;$i++ )
{
  echo"hi1"; // this is printed 10 times
  $building_type = mysql_fetch_array($building_types);
  echo $building_type; // prints Array 2 times not 10 times ...
  if ( $building_type === FALSE ) echo"hi2"; //this is printed the last 8 times ...
```

Thanks,

Comment: Problem solved, culprit was an overloaded variable,
note to others, check for overloaded variables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug was due to reuse of variable $building_types,

Answer (score 0):

Try using a while loop

E.g.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($building_types)) {
    echo $row['ColumnName'];
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, originally I used a while loop but when this didn't work I tried using a for loop to see if it would help me debug, I've fixed it now I think, culprit was an overloaded variable. Thanks anyway.